# How to access the request parameter of one controller in a different controller in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I have a controller that takes say String customerId as a request parameter, I can access it in the same controller method by the @requestParam, Now I render a form that has a button with corresponding action that basically calls a second controller. Next in this controller itself, I need to access the customerId to do more validations.How do I access the original customerId in this second controller?

Also, in case I perform the validations of the next controller, in the first controller itself, (I can easily do this), then I can pass a success/failure boolean to the next controller, that displays success/failure content. But I do not know what should the action of the button be kept in this case.

Can someone illustrate and explain (code preferred) any/both of these methods and which would be better?

Comment: You can simple redirect the method response to another RequestMapping.

Comment: Controllers should be designed to do one thing and one thing well. Make sure they are not designed to be reliant or have to know the workings of each other.

Answer (score 0):

Why not attach another custom listener to the button created in your dynamic form and pass the customer ID as a parameter?

a controller like this

```
public class TestController implements ActionListener
{
    private String id;

    public TestController(String id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        // do something with the id
    }
}
```